# ELI5 to understand when to use Dispatchers.Main

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am reading about coroutines, and I am trying to understand why should I use, for example,

```
fun main() {
  launch(Dispatchers.Main){
     // dosomething
  }
}
```

instead of directly:

```
fun main() {
 //do something
}
```

I am already on main thread, does it make any sense to do that something inside a coroutine block?

Is a question to comprehend better a teoretic problem.

Comment: This is not about choosing a thread. This is about being in a coroutine/suspending context. You can't use a suspending code directly in `main`. Try to do e.g. `delay()` and you'll see it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` function of a JVM app has nothing to do with the "main" thread. The "main thread" that Dispatchers.Main corresponds with only exists in UI frameworks like Swing, JavaFx, or Android.

Therefore, your example doesn't make sense, since there is no main thread in that app. If you tried to run that code, and were calling it on an actual CoroutineScope so it could be resolved, the app would crash because there is no Dispatchers.Main to use.

On Android, all the framework lifecycle functions like `onPause`, `onCreate`, etc. and all the UI listeners (button click listeners) are called on the main thread by the OS (or Compose backend). Therefore, most of your own code is already going to be called on the main thread.

Most of the other classes Android provides are also designed to use the main thread by default. For example, if you start a TimerTask, the callback will be fired on the main thread.

Also, most UI classes *must* be used only on the main thread to work properly or without causing a crash.

Occasionally, you might be working with background threads, such as when using a third party library that needs to offload work from the main thread. In order to call code on the main thread again, you might choose to use a coroutine that is using Dispatchers.Main as a convenient way to do so.

This should be a rare situation as most libraries on Android already support running callbacks on the main thread. And if you're using coroutines anyway, you generally are not going to be launching child coroutines to return to the main thread. Probably, if you're working with the UI, you're already using `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`, so Dispatchers.Main is already the default for your coroutines.

In most cases where I have seen examples of launching a coroutine to get back to the main thread, the person is doing it defensively when they don't need to. I consider this a code smell, because it shows they are confused about what thread their code is already running on.